# textarea javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите команду для того, чтобы с помощью javascript заполнить нужным текстом textarea.
Так выглядит контрол который я пытаюсь заполнить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже пробовал команду:

`element = document.getElementById("body");`

`element.value="text text text text text text";`

При выполнении указанной команды, текст в Textarea вставляется.
Но при отправке формы через кнопку submit.
Содержимое Textarea исчезает.
И генерится ошибка о том, что я должен был заполнить Textarea.
Если текст вводить вручную то он сабмитится без проблем.

[ссылка на код изучаемой странички](https://yadi.sk/d/uWj_aqmKpgH-Mg)

На самом деле этот javascript код я пытаюсь выполнить из powershell + selenium
пытаюсь так
`$element = $ie.FindElementByID("body")`
`$str = "`$(`'#body`').append(arguments[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWS8m.png));"
$str = "`$(`'#textarea`').append(arguments[1]);"`
`$str = "`$(arguments[0]).val(arguments[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWS8m.png));"
$ie.executeScript("arguments[0].append(arguments[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWS8m.png));", $element, $message)`
И для каждого варианта $str я получаю ошибку. "unknown error: $ is not defined
наверно executeScript не умеет jquery

Comment: Может на textarea добавлено событие, которое задает значение какой-то переменной при ручном вводе... а submit сначала проверяет её, потом отправляет. Нужен код...

Comment: Может, так: $('#textarea').append(text);

Comment: А если больше 20-ти знаков вставить?

Comment: Если больше 20-ти знаков тоже самое. Я просто слово text привел для примера и не обратил внимания, что минимум 20 знаков.

Comment: В вопросе добавил ссылку на код странички.

Comment: команда $element.append("text text text text text text text text "): даже не внесла текст в textarea

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте повесить событие change на элемент, после того как изменили его value.

https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change#sobytie-change

Comment: Старайтесь давать более развернутые ответы, содержащие примеры кода, ссылки можете скидывать в комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это. Сначала нажимая кнопку PushOnMe заполняете textarea. Потом нажимая кнопку submit отправляете без потери textarea value. Для проверки раскоментируйте php code внизу и проверьте на той же странице.

```js
<script>

  function fortextarea() {
    var val = document.getElementById('div').value;
    var textarea = document.getElementById('body');
    textarea.innerHTML = val;
  }

  </script>
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
  <textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea><br>
  <input id="div" value="PushOnMe" type="submit" onclick="fortextarea()" ;><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<!-- <?php 
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {
echo $_POST['body'];
 }
?> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте jquery:

```
$(element).val("text text text text text text");
```

Comment: Насамом деле этот javascript код я пытаюсь выполнить из powershell + selenium  
пытаюсь так  
    $element = $ie.FindElementByID("body")  
    $str = "`$(`'#body`').append(arguments[1]);"  
    $str = "`$(`'#textarea`').append(arguments[1]);"  
    $str = "`$(arguments[0]).val(arguments[1]);"  
    $ie.executeScript("arguments[0].append(arguments[1]);", $element, $message)  
И для каждого варианта $str я получаю ошибку. "unknown error: $ is not defined  
наверно executeScript не умеет jquery